# check and uncheck check boxes by clicking through a series of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check and uncheck boxes when i am clicking through a series of divs. For example I have a list of three divs and each div correspond to one check box. When I select one div I should be checking a box and unchecking the box selected before with the previous click.

Here is my html

```
<div class="trigger">1</div>
<div class="trigger">2</div>
<div class="trigger">3</div>

<input id="one" type="checkbox">
<input id="two" type="checkbox">
<input id="three" type="checkbox">
```

and js

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').eq($(this).index('.trigger')).attr('checked', true);
});
```

The process runs fine for the first loop and stops working after the first iteration. Here is the fiddle. Cant figure out what am I doing wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/GS7p8/5/

Comment: That's what's called "radio buttons" - try using them. Anyways, you should use `prop` to set the `checked` state: http://jsfiddle.net/E64KW/ . Seems to work for me. When you're setting an `attribute`, you should've been using `.attr("checked", "checked")` to check it and then **`removeAttr("checked")`** to uncheck it.

Comment: @ Ian--if I had a choice of using radio button I would have. This a drupal module which is not giving me that option. So I am writing a quick hack

Comment: @hariharan-- I looked at that before. it wasnt really what I was looking for. So I wouldnt say it is a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').eq($(this).index('.trigger')).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VckSz/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using prop instead of attr

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
$('input[type=checkbox]').eq($(this).index('.trigger')).prop('checked', true);
```